# Instantiate a class or not?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm looking at some lwjgl's tutorials and occurred to me instead of keeping the class instantiated in a variable, instantiate it and call the method directly without saving the object.

I was wondering if it's good to do this when you don't have to reuse the object later, or whether it is best to always keep the object.

I mean this:

```
(new Lesson02()).run(fullscreen);
```

instead it:

```
Lesson02 l2 = new Lesson02();
l2.run(fullscreen);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doubt settled. Thanks to all! :)

Comment: Just a note... the parenthesis around the constructor call are not required. `new Lession02().run(fullscreen);` should work all the same. I think the parenthesis look goofy unless this is nested in some larger expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really any difference if you do not plan to use the object later. So option 1 is fine. If you follow option 2 and end up not using `l2` later in the code then it will get garbage collected anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you do not have to use the object later then the first option should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the first option unless there is a lot of parameters to the constructor and function, then I prefer to split it for readability. General rule: use whatever is more understandable and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java is a garbage collected language, the first way is perfectly accepted. I would prefer it for its compactness and clutterlessness over the second one.

Answer (score 2):

The two options are practically identical.

If the compiler is bad at optimising then the first one may infinitesimally be faster, because it is more likely to be quickly reclaimed by the GC.

Answer (score 2):

The former option will create a temporary reference variable anyway; named or unnamed, you have a local variable referencing an object on the heap. If it's never used again, the garbage collector will clean up for you.

The two options differ only in readability and so you can select the one you prefer from that standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is best accepted because Java can allocate memory for you.

Comment: The JVM allocates memory for the Lesson02 object, either way.